# ItextSharp: Positioning text on page in a loop

Tags: pdf, loops, position, itext, absolute

I found this code to place  text on a page at a particular position.

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
Phrase myText = new Phrase("TEST paragraph\nNewline");
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, 34, 750, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.Go();
```

Now I wish to do so in a forlooop for a series of text. I have

```
columnText ct = new ColumnText(cb)
Phrase myText; int x = 34; int y = 750;
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
  myText = new Phrase("TEST paragraph\nNewline");
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, x, y, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  ct.Go();
  x += 10;
  y+= 12;
}
```

But this gives me an error as the document fails to create.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the object creation into the loop:

```
//Declare ct
columnText ct;
Phrase myText; int x = 34; int y = 750;
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
  //Instantiate ct
  ct = new ColumnText(cb);
  myText = new Phrase("TEST paragraph\nNewline");
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, 34, 750, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  ct.Go();
  x += 10;
  y += 12;
}
```